# jQuery : loop through nested objects

Tags: jquery, loops, object, nested, each

I would like to loop trough nested objects. here is my code :

```
var defaults = {
    toolTips: {
        printVersion: {
            toolTip1: {
                link_s: '#mm_tooltip1_link',
                tooltip_s: '#mm_tooltip1'
            },
            toolTip2: {
                link_s: '#mm_tooltip2_link',
                tooltip_s: '#mm_tooltip2'
            },
            toolTip3: {
                link_s: '#mm_tooltip3_link',
                tooltip_s: '#mm_tooltip3'
            }
        }
    }
};

var settings;
var $archives_dialog;

$.madmagz = function(options) {
    settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
    init();
};

function init(){
    initToolTips();
}

function initToolTips() {
    $(settings.toolTips).each ( function (i, tooltip_group) {
        $(tooltip_group).each (function (i, tooltip) {
            // do stuff
        });
    });
}
```

In every each loop, I get the same object. How can I go down in every nested objects ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the `$.each()` helper method to loop over objects.

```
function initToolTips() {
    $.each(defaults.toolTips, function(i, tooltip_group) {
        $.each(tooltip_group, function(i2, tooltip) {
            alert(i2);
        });
    });
}
```

Ref.: [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

Answer (score -1):

Use .children()

http://api.jquery.com/children/